# dependencyManagement and scope

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I usually put a `<dependencyManagement>` section in `parent-project/pom.xml`. This `<dependencyManagement>` section contains declaration and version for all dependencies of my children modules like this (i.e. without the `<scope>` element):

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies> 
</dependencyManagement>
```

In all children modules (i.e. moduleX/pom.xml), I have:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Obviously, in this example I'm repeating the `<scope>test</scope>` multiple times for the same dependency (once in every child module needing junit).

My question is:
What are the best practices regarding `<scope>` declaration?
Is it better to put it in the `<dependencyManagement>`?
Or is it better to put it in the `<dependencies>` section of the child module (like in this post)? And why?
Is there any definitive answer to this question?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A little late to the party, but I'll add my two cents.

I recently ran into a very difficult to debug issue.
I have a parent pom for managing dependencies across multiple projects.  I had it set with all the dependencies common amongst them and included `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version` and the *most common `scope`*.
My thinking would be that I would not have to include scope in the actual dependency section in each project if it fell in line with that *most common `scope`*.
The problem occurred when some of those dependencies showed up as transitive dependencies.  For example, if:

- A depends on B at compile scope.
- B depends on C at compile scope.
- C is set to provided in `dependencyManagement` of parent.

Then A's transitive dependency on C is determined to be provided.  I'm not really sure if that makes sense or not, but it certainly is confusing.

Anyway, save yourself the hassle, and leave `scope` out of your `dependencyManagement`.

Comment: it makes sense but is not well documented, see http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/DependencyManagement-to-force-scope-td112273.html, i edit my answer below

Comment: summary: "leave scope out of your dependencyManagement" :)

Answer (score 39):

`dependencyManagement` is just here to define dependencies version for all project submodules, the only pertinent scope in this section is `import` for BOMs.

Scope must be defined in `dependencies` section.

*(For a given dependency it determines the usage context. It allows to include the dependency only when it is required for execution. For example an ear will not be packaged with Java-ee dependencies (scope  `provided`) as it will find them on the target server.)*

**[edit]**

The first statement has an exception, the scope `provided` in `dependencyManagement` section will override defined scope in `dependencies` sections. see [DependencyManagement to force scope](https://web.archive.org/web/20190208204740/http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/DependencyManagement-to-force-scope-td112273.html)

Comment: "the only pertinent scope in this section is import" does it mean that if I put the scope `test` in the `dependendcyManagement` : it has no effect ?

Comment: In fact it seems i am not totally right cf. http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/DependencyManagement-to-force-scope-td112273.html `dependencyManagement` scope have an interest

Answer (score 9):

As with other answers, best practice is to exclude scope from dependencyManagement and explicitly specify it when defining the dependency.  It is a rare case that you would want a different version of the same dependency in different scopes, e.g., one version when compiling your app and a different when running it -- the only case I can think of is you want to explicitly run your tests against a different version of a library in case users use that version instead of the one you specify.

If you define scope in dependencyManagement, it restricts the use of that version to ONLY the defined scope -- so any other scopes will pick up a random version of the dependency.  I ran into this yesterday when we had defined junit 4.12 in dependencyManagement with test scope, but our common test framework module used junit with compile scope, so it picked up version 4.8.2 instead.

Comment: I don't think that's correct (anymore perhaps, at least with Maven 3.8.6). `mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose` showed that a `compile` `dependency` picked up the version from a `provided` `dependencyManagement`.

Answer (score 2):

super late to the party, but the latest maven has very clear documentation on the transitive dependency scope and dependencyManagement details, including one example.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope
from the documentation we can see:

1. when transitive scopes are different, there are precedence rules governing which one will be applied. At the first glance the rules table is complicated, but it makes common sense for most cases.
2. the documentation specifically has an example of dependency scope and dependencyManagement combined case. ultimately it follows the rules specified in 1.

As a conclusion, it's recommended to include scope in the most 'common' ways. If there are transitive, conflicting or cornered cases, we need to carefully check the precedence rules.

Answer (score 1):

There is no gain in adding a single dependency to the dependency management, for any scope. All you have is the duplication. If you want to have the version configurable, add a property and use it in your dependency:

```
<properties>
        <junit.version>4.10</junit.version> 
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, there are cases where the dependency management shines - when you are using `boms` in order to orchestrate the versions for a larger collections of artifacts, like using a certain version of a Java EE implementation:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee6.with.tools.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
....
```

Comment: dependencyManagement (even with one single dependency) is the only location where artifact version are defined. In my opinion, this only fact is enough to use it. Using a property is useful since you have multiple artifacts that comes always with the same versionId (for instance spring modules)

Comment: Another reason to use dependencyManagement is to exclude unwanted transitive dependencies for a dependency centrally.

Comment: Another reason to use a property for version is so that you can quickly check for dependency version updates using `mvn versions:display-property-updates` -- as long as you take care to name your version properties in the `artifactId.version` pattern