# Creating uber jar with maven

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

My project inherits it's `compile` dependencies from parent and I have no control over it  - can't change them to `provided`.
 Additionally, I have added another dependency `'a:b:1.0.0'` to my project's pom. I want to include only `'a:b:1.0.0'` with it's own dependencies (**recursively** ) to my uber jar.  
Seems like neither `assembly` nor `shade` plugin doesn't support such case.
How this could be done ?
Thanks

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. You want 1) to change scope of an inherited dependency and 2) only pack `a:b` (groupId and artifactId) without the version name in the file?

Comment: "I want to include only 'a:b:1.0.0' with it's own dependencies (recursively ) to my uber jar. "

Comment: It's not about maven plugins then but about Maven dependency mediation, you can configure your `dependencyManagement` to override the dependencies scope of inherited dependencies, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221299/dependencymanagement-and-scope) post for example

Comment: Thanks @A_Di-Matteo, but this solves first part of the issue, how do I tell 'assembly' or 'shade' plugin to include 'a:b:1.0.0' **together** with it's dependencies, recursively ?

Comment: can you share your `pom.xml` file and what you already tried (and is not working)?

Answer (score 0):

Shading recursively has some significant disadvantages. Especially, the problem of duplicate files from multiple dependencies being overwritten with only a single version of the file. This can cause some pretty annoying problems to troubleshoot at runtime. You'd be better off using something like spring boot to build a standalone jar where instead of shading files into a single hierarchy, will embed dependent libraries into itself as a subdirectory and include on the classpath for you.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html