# What tags should be set in dependencyManagement

Tags: maven, dependency-management

Besides the `<version>` tag, I usually avoid adding tags to dependencies declared in `dependencyManagement`. This is because I never know how that will work out.

For instance:

- exclusion tag: won't work in import
  [Import Dependency Management with Exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276024/import-dependency-management-with-exclusion)
- scope: seems to be a mess of its own
  [dependencyManagement and scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221299/dependencymanagement-and-scope)
- type: if I use 2 different types I'll have to declare them both in the `dependencyManagement` section, in 2 separate dependencies

The maven documentation seems to be lacking some details in this regards.

So, what tags should I include in the dependencies of the `dependencyManagement` section?

Answer (score 0):

This depends very much on what you want to achieve.

In most cases, you do not need additional tags.

But if you want your dependency to be a test dependency (like `junit`), use `test` scope. And if you want to filter out dependencies which are provided by your application server, use `provided` scope.

Furthermore, you can set exclusions, but not on BOMs.

Type declarations are rarely necessary because you usually manage jars. But if you e.g. manage ejb dependencies, use `ejb` as type.

Comment: I usually want to have a central place where all dependencies are managed. So I expect tags added to dependencyManagement to be "inherited" by all dependencies. Corner cases would be the exception.

Comment: So `junit` should probably have a `test` scope, and ejbs should have type `ejb`.